# iOS PDFKit's PDFView not scrollable

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

Trying to create a simple PDF viewer using PDFKit. The PDF file is visible as expected but it is not scrollable vertically. The PDFView is created programmatically inside another UIView subclass as shown below:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class MyPDFViewerView: UIView {
    
    private var pdfFileURL: String?
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    
    private let pdfView: PDFView
    
    // MARK: - Init
    
    init(fileURL: String) {
        self.pdfFileURL = fileURL
        pdfView = PDFView(frame: .zero)
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        createComponents()
        addConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) not yet implementd")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup UI
    
    private func createComponents() {
        [pdfView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.pageBreakMargins = .zero
    }
    
    private func addConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    
    func loadPDFDocument() {
        guard let fileURLString = pdfFileURL else {
            return
        }
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURLString) {
            return
        }
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURLString)
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }
    }
}
```

The class MyPDFViewerView is added as a subview in a UIViewController's view. What am I doing wrong here ?

Tried delaying the insertion of view MyPDFViewerView as a subview of ViewController's view but still no luck.